# How can I create a keyboard shortcut for VS Code to open a new external terminal?

Tags: visual-studio-code, alacritty

I want to change the terminal for a better presentation of my project, so I don't want to use the integrated VS Code terminal, I would like to use my system's own terminal which is Alacritty (I'm using linux)

I've been changing the settings in VSCode's settings.json file, but no matter how hard I try I couldn't get the `Ctrl + j` command to open the alacritty terminal as a floating terminal.

What I want to achieve is almost the same as with AstroNvim, when using the open terminal floating command, it opens Alacritty as a float.

Comment: read the doc page about terminals and if it isn't there it probably can't be done

Comment: Why don't you just bring up an Alacritty window and do your runs there?  It's only two or three more keystrokes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The keyboard command ID you're looking for is `workbench.action.terminal.openNativeConsole`. Ex. in keybindings.json (open using `Preferences: Open Keyboard Shortcuts (JSON)` in the [command palette](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface#_command-palette)):

```json
{
    "key": "", // TODO: pick something.
    "command": "workbench.action.terminal.openNativeConsole",
    "when": "!terminalFocus",
},
```

If you want to use <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>j</kbd>, then put `"ctrl+j"` in the `key` property's value. But I wouldn't suggest doing that because <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>j</kbd> is the default binding for *toggling the panel's visibility*- not opening a new integrated terminal. So unless you plan to replace the keybinding for toggling the panel's visibility, or don't care to toggle the panel visibility with a keyboard shortcut, I'd suggest to use something else.

Comment: It's a great advance, but how do I make the terminal float?

Comment: @XNeyMo that probably belongs in a new question post.